# Template class calling template function - Linker Error

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I'm experimenting with template classes and functions, and I ran into the following error. I'm trying to call a template function from class Vertex with the template class from class RelationShipExpander. The MWE below yields the following linker error:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "typeinfo for PipeType", referenced from:
>       typeinfo for RelationShipExpander<in> in main.cpp.o
>   "vtable for PipeType", referenced from:
>       PipeType::PipeType() in main.cpp.o
>   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

// Abbrr
class Vertex;
typedef forward_list<const Vertex*> edge_list;

/*
 * Matching
 */
struct match_first {
    match_first(unsigned value) : value(value) {};

    template<class A>
    bool operator()(const pair<const unsigned, A> &a) {
        return a.first == value;
    }

    unsigned value;
};

/*
 * Edge Indirection
 */
struct in {
    static edge_list& get_list(pair<edge_list, edge_list> &a) {
        return a.first;
    }
};

struct out {
    static edge_list& get_list(pair<edge_list, edge_list> &a) {
        return a.second;
    }
};


class Vertex {
public:
    template<class Direction>
    edge_list &get_edges(unsigned relation_id) {
        auto i = find_if(neigh_set.begin(), neigh_set.end(), match_first(relation_id));

        if (i != neigh_set.end()) {
            return Direction::get_list(i->second);
        }

        // throw except.
    }

private:
    vector<pair<const unsigned, pair<edge_list, edge_list>>> neigh_set;
};



class PipeType {
public:
    /*
     * Mutators
     */
    virtual void Pipe(Vertex& gremlin);
};



template <class Direction>
class RelationShipExpander: PipeType {
public:
    /*
     *  Constructor
     */
    RelationShipExpander(unsigned relationship_id) : relationship_id(relationship_id) {};

    /*
     *  Mutators
     */
    void Pipe(Vertex& gremlin) {
        gremlin.get_edges<Direction>(relationship_id);
    };
private:
    unsigned relationship_id;
};



int main() {
    RelationShipExpander<in> expand_in(1);
}
```

Comment: After fixing the missing include [it works fine](https://ideone.com/m44il6). Did you let intellisense confuse you with red squigglies that are not actually errors?

Comment: I'm working in CLion, adding the algorithm include does not work for me though. Strange---Added a complete description of the error.

Comment: `main.cpp.o` is weird. Unless your source is main.cpp.cpp, it is more commonly main.o. Could you build using a source different than what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PipeType` *is* different in that the member function seems to not have a definition. Just like the compiler says:

> "vtable for PipeType", referenced from:
>         PipeType::PipeType() in main.cpp.o
>     NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

If you intend `PipeType` to be an interface, you can make the function pure virtual by adding `= 0` instead of a function body. You cannot just skip the implementation, even if it is implemented in the derived class.

```
class PipeType {
public:
    virtual void Pipe(Vertex& gremlin) = 0;
};
```

If you intend the class to have the function implemented, you of course will have to add that implementation somewhere. Either in the header or in one of the .cpp files.

Comment: Wow, totally overlooked that. Shame on me, Thanks alot.